# How can I make it so that my MVC 5 project no longer automatically inherits from ApiController when creating a Controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api2

I have my Web API in the same solution, but different project, and now, whenever I create a Controller in my MVC 5 (non-Web API project), it inherits from ApiController, instead of Controller. It also includes the default using statements related to the Web API, which is not what I want at all.

How do I make it inherit from Controller instead of ApiController?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the default settings (in Visual Studio 2013), *Add...* --> *Controller* under the context menu for the Controllers folder will open up the add scaffold dialog. There are options for MVC 5, Web API 2, and Web API 2 OData controllers that are included.

MVC 5 will by default inherit from `Controller`, while the Web API 2 varieties will default to inherit `ApiController`. This is regardless of project type.

Comment: Yep, just checked it and that is correct! Not sure how I was missing something so obvious.

Comment: Too many coffee driven morning in a row do that to me, but YMMV ... :)